# Setting a user-data-dir with headless Chrome in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to get headless Chrome to work while setting a user data dir using the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=./User_Data') 
options.add_argument('--headless')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

This returns this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

none of the following prevents this message from showing up (as suggested here: [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t))

```
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
```

The only thing I could find that prevents this error from showing up is adding this argument:

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=45447')
```

This at least starts up a headless Chrome, but still does not pick up the user dir specified, when running without the headless argument everything seems to be working as expected.

How do I get a headless chrome to use the user data dir?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)

Comment: none of the suggestions given help me out in this case unfortunately. Headless chrome runs fine without a the --user-data-dir argument, it is only when the argument is added that the error occurs

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems that this problem is a bug inside chrome driver.

Comment: So it is not possible to run headless chrome with --user-data-dir argument, or with a specific profile?