# Uow to run headless browser for scraping with python selenium with tkinter

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I try to build a bot which automatically scrapes website by making Exe file of python script. For scraping I use python selenium and for user interface I use tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.master = master
    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
       self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
       self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
       self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
       self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

       self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                          command=self.master.destroy)
       self.quit.pack(side="bottom")
    

    def say_hi(self):
       chrome_path=r"C:\Users\ANISH JAIN\Documents\PYTHON_PROGRAMME\ABOTS\chromedriver.exe"
       chrome_options = Options()
       chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=./User_Data')
       chrome_options.add_argument('-headless')
       driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
       driver.get('https://web.telegram.org/#/login')
    
       sleep(20)
       contact_class = 'im_dialog_peer'
       contacts_sel = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(contact_class)
       contacts = []
       for cs in contacts_sel:
        contacts.append(cs.text)
       print("Hi there!!!")
       print(contacts)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('350x450+700+200')
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

when
`chrome_options.add_argument('-headless')`
this code is commented everything works fine but when it is uncommented code  gives
this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

Comment: Hi - FYI scrap/scrapping means throwing away - use scrape/scraping

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697169/setting-a-user-data-dir-with-headless-chrome-in-selenium) may help.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter. Can you get the same problem if you strip out all of the tkinter code?

Comment: @bryan oakley its happen only with with gui

Comment: Just to be clear: you're saying that if you put `say_hi` into a separate file with no tkinter code at all, it behaves differently than if it's called from a tkinter button? That seems very surprising.

Comment: guys that's question please try to run above code you get what i am trying to say